# Z3 Command-line Timeout

Tags: z3

When using Z3 on the command line with the "-T" switch, is there a way to set the timeout to less than one second?

I know you can set the timeout to be less than that using the API, but for various stupid reasons I've been passing text files containing SMT-LIBv2 scripts to Z3 in a loop (please don't be mad), thinking it would work just as well. I've only just noticed that this approach seems to create a lower bound of one second on timeouts. This slows things down quite a bit if I'm using Z3 to check thousands of short files.

I understand if this is just the way things are, and I accept that what I'm doing isn't sensible when there's already a perfectly good API for Z3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options:

1. You can use "soft timeouts". They are less reliable than the timeout /T because soft timeout expiration is only checked periodically. Nevertheless, the option "smt.soft_timeout=10" would set a timeout of 10ms (instead of 10s). You can set the these options both from the command-line and within the SMT-LIB2 file using (set-option :smt.soft_timeout 10). The tutorial on using tactics/solvers furthermore explains how to use more advanced features (strategies) and you can also control these advanced features using options, such as timeouts, from the textual interface.
2. You can load SMT-LIB2 files from the programmatic API. The assertions from the files are stored in a conjunction. You can then call a solver (again from the API) and use the "soft timeout" option for the solver object. There isn't really a reason to use option 2 unless you need to speed up your pipe or use something more than the soft timeout feature because it is already reasonably exposed for the SMT-LIB level.